# How to replace route parameters in url template?

Tags: angular, typescript, url, angular-routing

The angular router uses route parameters like `:productId` to match routes and to build the parameters map.

I'd like to do the opposite. Given a url template like `/products/:productId/components` (as a string) and a parameters map, I'd like to fill in the placeholders in the url template.

Is there an easy way to do this?

---

**Update:**

Here is a trivial implementation that works:

```
let parts = urlTemplate.split('/');  // urlTemplate might be something like '/products/:productId/components'
parts = parts.map(p => {
  if (p.startsWith(':')) {
    return paramMap.get(p.substr(1));
  } else {
    return p;
  }
});
const url = parts.join('/');         // could be something like '/products/27/components'
```

I was hoping to find an approach where I don't need to do url parsing myself (because there might me more complex urls which won't work with the approach above), but letting the angular router do the replacement.
However, for my use-case, the trivial implementation above might actually be good enough.

Comment: I think, at least I, need more information. Are you looking for an easy string replace method, or what are you trying to do? What do you mean with url template? do you have any code in which you tried it, or can you explain it with pseudo code?

Comment: @PierreDuc I updated my question - and I might actually have just answered it myself.... :)

Comment: Yep, angular does not provide any helper functions for such task, and your solution will work fine

Comment: That's good to know. Thanks!